# Trying to add a private zone to a website

Tags: web-development, authentication

I'm trying to add a "login page" as soon as someone clicks on the Galerie, in order to keep the pictures only between the members of the school.

I tried several options, even designed a page named "login.htm" but I can't get it to work the way I want! I'd like a single username and password, so no need to setup a database.

Otherwise, I was thinking about creating a new "sub-domain" and a new website attached to it, and just link it from the Galerie page.

Does anyone have a good idea how I can do it? It also has to be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to VGA fess that will do it. Check out: http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/ for a tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you use [htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess)? It might be what you need.

Comment: Morning! True, it could be a good solution. I'll check it out a bit deeper. Thanks.